# Get a specific Child of a Node in XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xml-parsing

I am sorry to need to ask this easy question, but I have really tried everything, but nothing worked so far. So, I want to check, whether a slidelink has been selected.

The XML:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
           <nav_data>
               <outline>
                   <links>
                      <slidelink>
                          <links>
                               <slidelink/>
                               <slidelink/>
                               <slidelink/>
                          </links>
                      </slidelink>
                      <slidelink>
                          <links>
                               <slidelink/>
                               <slidelink/>
                               <slidelink/>
                         </links>
                      </slidelink>
                    </links>
                 </outline>
            </nav_data>
```

My failed code to get the node and output it to the stage:

```
var nav_data:XML = new XML(e.target.data);  
var parentNode:XMLList = nav_data.outline.links.slidelink[0].links.slidelink[1];
textfeld_txt.text = parentNode;
```

I have also tried `children()[1]` but didn't work. If I change my variable to:

```
var parentNode:XMLList = nav_data.outline.links.slidelink[0].links.slidelink;
```

every slidelink is outputed on the stage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When XMLList has one node object, `toString()` returns element text.
Now, `slidelink` node object has no element text.

If you want to verify selected XMLList, use `toXMLString()`

```
textfeld_txt.text = parentNode.toXMLString();
```